# CSS Selector for nth element regardless of parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector for the nth of a matching element, regardless of any parents.

e.g. in the following how to select just "The second paragraph." without also the fourth one?

```
<div>
   <p>The first paragraph.</p>
   <p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
   <p>The third paragraph.</p>
   <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

I thought p:nth-oftype(2) would do it but that selects both the second and fourth (which is the 2nd of each parent div).

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/km4nbfz9/

EDIT - This is just ONE example bit of HTML, question is how to make this work for the n'th element that matches CSS selector regardless of parents and structure.

Comment: have a look on **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child)**

Comment: The DOM is a tree. So if you think about it, a node depends always on its parent.

Comment: you can't just do without parent, If you can do so I will give you upvote

Comment: For ma_dev_15 and @pullata-praveen now I know its not possible in a broader sense (the real markup I am working with is much much more complex than given in the example). I can use a different technique. Likely jQuery to get an array of all elements, then get nth from that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## NO

The [**spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) says:

> The :nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 ***siblings*** before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, and has a ***parent*** element.

There is no *nth-of-DOM* selector.

The operative word here is **siblings**..which requires a parent, not uncles or grandparents etc.

As mentioned in the comments by [@Marcos Pérez Gude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude)

*"The DOM is a tree. So if you think about it, a node depends always on its parent."*

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
div:nth-of-type(1) p:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    div:first-of-type p:nth-of-type(2) {
        background: red;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
        <div class="highlight">
       <p>The first paragraph.</p>
       <p>The second paragraph.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
       <p>The third paragraph.</p>
       <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
    </div>
```

Add `class` or `id` to the div to highlight `the second paragraph` only and using `class` or `id` you have to style otherwise every 2nd element inside a div will get highlighted

```
 .highlight p:nth-child(0n+2) {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: if you have any solution other than this please find and post here when you don't have an idea other than this don't discourage by saying not useful

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but you should look at the broader question than just the example code provided. Your example will work if the first `div` or the `div` with `class='highlight'` has two `p`. What if the second `p` is part of the second `div`? What if their structure is dynamic?

Comment: Steady on chaps - *I* didn't down-vote you. BUT if you read the question again you will see that its a general question about 'regardless of parent' not about how to make it work with that one *example* - so you didn't answer the question and thats why you were downvoted I expect. If you can't take criticism then maybe the internet isn't for you?

Comment: i think user does not even know the basics of selectors where to use and how to use and in what conditions it is used

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because you aren't answering the **broader** question. Yes, your code works **in the example code** but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: ..and THAT **is** the answer. Sometimes a simple NO *is* the right answer.